# How to solve this function problem in python

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to import a function from another python file and place it into a button function. This is the code I've written personally:

```
def press_btn1():
    text = entry1.get()
    if text == "something":
        test()
        return None
```

Comment: oh, also the test() function is in ananother file (also .py)

Comment: `from myotherfile import test` should do it. Note: `from myotherfile` *not* `from myotherfile.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that you have two .py files main_file and sub_file

So in sub_file, I have a function called `print_hello()` that prints hello.

This is in sub_file:

```
def print_hello():
    print('hello')
```

So to access this function in main_file you have to import sub_file and call the function in the sub_file:

This is in main_file:

```
import sub_file

sub_file.print_hello()
```

so this gives the output as `hello`

Now you can use this concept in you code

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the below scenario:

In File also.py , you have test function:

```
def test():
 ...
 ...
```

In your main (assuming main.py), where you are using test()  :

```
import also as a
..
..
..
def press_btn1():
    text = entry1.get()
    if text == "something":
        a.test()
        return None
```

**MAKE SURE the also.py and main.py are in the same directory**

If they are in the different directory, then [read this](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/)

Comment: thanks a lot! Its my First day of stackoverflow and THIS was SO HELPFUL, thanks!